# how to convert epoch time to local time in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript

I have the following epoch time `1374188400000000` which is :

```
GMT: Thu, 18 Jul 2013 23:00:00 GMT
local time zone: 7/19/2013 12:00:00 AM GMT+1
```

How can I update the epoch so that it contains the local date time(1 day ahead) instead of the original date time?

I tried the following but does not work:

```
var utcSeconds = 1374188400000000;
var d = new Date(0); // The 0 there is the key, which sets the date to the epoch
d.setUTCSeconds(utcSeconds);
```

Comment: Are you creating a date object from the epoch time and wanting to amend that, or are you wanting to update the epoch time itself?

Comment: if its possible to update the epoch time itself then that is preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this issue by converting the epoch date time to a date object and this way the time difference is calculated automatically then I formatted the date using a custom function.

```
dashboards.formatDate = function (ticks) {

    var date = new Date(ticks);

    var months = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar",
    "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep",
    "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");

    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var year = date.getFullYear();

    return day + " " + months[month] + ", " + year;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want exactly one day ahead and are not bothered by accuracy or anything else the quickest way to do it is to just add 86400 (1 day in seconds) to the epoch you have.

Comment: I want to convert it to the local time so that its calculated correctly if accessed globally.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the simplest way to achieve it but it seems to work.

Using your epoch you can create a date object but you need to trim 3 numbers from the right as your number is too long.

```
var epoch = 1374188400000000;
var epoch2 = parseInt((""+epoch).substring(0,13), 10);
var dt = new Date(epoch2);
dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+1);
alert(dt); //Sat Jul 20 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time) 
alert(dt.valueOf()); //1374274800000
```

From your original number I convert to a string, trim to 13 characters, create a new date object and call `setDate()` to add 1 day to your date. You can convert this back to milliseconds by calling `.valueOf()` on your date object.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7y7LD/1/)

Comment: but what if the local time is two days ahead? surely then this wouldn't work as it only adds a day.

Comment: ? Your original question states `How can I update the epoch so that it contains the local date time(1 day ahead) instead of the original date time?` You may need to clarify what you are trying to achieve?